# Why is it なくて and not ないで

Tags: grammar, negation

> お金が足りなくて、本が買えませんでした。

Shouldn't it be:

> お金が足り*ないで*、本が買えませんでした。

Comment: Both ないで and なくて can express causality, but in this case, なくて is more used than the other.

Comment: ^`in this case, なくて is more used than the other` -- んん。。？ You mean お金が足り**ないで** 、本が買えませんでした is acceptable? I don't think it's grammatically correct...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ないで doesn't stand for reason/cause (but a condition without the object). Now, in this example, shortage of money is the reason why you couldn't buy the book. So, you can't use it.