# Trouble ないで vs なくて

Tags: grammar

In this [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5926/32056) it is said that the usage of なくて is narrower than ないで(ないで can always replace なくて according to the logic explained and is ambiguous because of that)

But in this [question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/63175/why-is-it-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A6-and-not-%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7), the answer says that ないで cannot replace なくて in the sentence discussed.

What is the reason behind that?

Comment: Please read the first answer again. It doesn't say "ないで can always replace なくて". That's a logial fallacy. It refers to 二者択一 and 付帯状況 but not reason/cause, which is the key to solve the problem in the second link.